# Touch Draw Issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, quartz-core

What's the problem in my code, cause when I'm doing a new point. The previous point is automatically made a new straight line that's connected to my current point.

here's my code

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480 , 320));
[drawView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480,320)];
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineCap(context,kCGLineCapRound);
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context,red, green, blue, 1.0);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, previousPoint1.x, previousPoint1.y, mid2.x, mid2.y);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
drawView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

Comment: Do you get an error?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code performs is drawing a a quadratic bézier curve going from mid1 to mid2 passing by previousPoint.

According to your variables names I guess that you either misused tAddQuadCurveToPoint by confusing the variables, either you have previousPoint1, mid1 and mid2 on the same line and so don't see anything else than a line.

Comment: Actually in that code I can manage to draw, but in the end of my previous line(end point) and by starting again a new line(starting point) there will be a straight line connecting to those 2 points.. How can I draw two line without getting connected to each other?

Comment: Try to add 

    CGContextBeginPath(context);

before your
     CGContextMoveToPoint(context, mid1.x, mid1.y);